# BeautifulSoup: How to remove empty tables, while preserving tables that are partially empty or not empty

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an old website originally created in MS Frontpage that I'm trying to defrontpagify.  I've written a BeautifulSoup script that does most of it.  Only thing left is to remove empty tables, eg tables with no text content or data in *any* of their `td` tags.

The problem I'm stuck on is that what I've tried so far removes the table if at least one its `td` tags contains no data, even if others do.  That removes all the tables in the entire document, including ones with data I want to preserve.

```
tags = soup.findAll('table',text=None,recursive=True) 
[tag.extract() for tag in tags]
```

Any suggestions how to only remove tables in which *none* of the td tags contain any data?  (I don't care if they contain `img` or empty anchor tags, as long as there's no text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.text` property. It retrieves all text content (recursive) within that element.

Example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = """
<table id="empty">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="with_text">
  <tr><td>hey!</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="with_text_in_one_row">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>hey!</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="no_text_but_img">
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="no_text_but_a">
  <tr><td><a></a></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="text_in_a">
  <tr><td><a>hey!</a></td></tr>
</table>

"""

soup = BS(html)
for table in soup.findAll("table" ,text=None,recursive=True):
    if table.text:
        print table["id"]
```

Outputs:

```
with_text
with_text_in_one_row
text_in_a
```

Comment: @ByronGibson: Can you show an example empty table from your file that is left after this?

Comment: Hey, sorry bout that, I misread the html, it wasn't empty after all.  Deleted my comment as soon as I realized it, but guess I wasn't quite fast enough.  Thanks!